# If the _header.html.erb shows the value for @current_user.name, why does post_controller.rb show it as nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I changed my User class to have_many posts, and posts to belong to :user.
After doing a rails db:reset, and then in posts_controller.rb new method, tried to set

```
   def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.user_id = @current_user.id
  end
```

Now, the _header.html.erb fills in the @current_user.name, but in the above new method of the posts_controller.rb, it gives an error that @current_user is nil and the field id is unknown.  How, do I set the user_id for the post?

Comment: try using `@post.user_id = current_user.id` - get rid of the `@` symbol. likely current_user is a helper method and you have likely not initialised the `@current_user`instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `@post.user_id = current_user.id` - get rid of the @ symbol. likely `current_user` is a helper method and you have likely not initialised the `@current_user` instance variable.

Comment: Apparently Post does not have a field 'user_id'.  I added has_many :user to Post and belongs_to :user to User after adding the User through the  devise package.  Do I need to explicitly add a user_id to Post through a migration?

Comment: @JohnWooten - you will need to do it explicitly: a post must belong to a user. and there must be a user_id column added to the posts table. This can be done with a migration. please paste your model.rb files above and your migration files if you are having further problems with this (but that is a different problem entirely to the original post made - the mods may not like it so you might have to ask a different question.)